# Can I have a namespace or hierarchy for resources in terraform? Or otherwise group resources together?

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code, hcl

As a specefic example, I have a group of subnets that are all used for the same thing, but are spread across multiple availabililty zones.

I'd like to be able to reference all of them as a list, so that I could do something like `aws_subnet.myname[*].id` to get all the subnet ids for that group of subnets.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specialized feature for grouping resources, but you can do it yourself using a named local value:

```
locals {
  subnets = flatten([aws_subnet.a, aws_subnet.b, aws_subnet.c])
}
```

The `flatten` call here is to normalize between resources with and without `count` set, since without `count` the resource expression returns just a single object while with `count` it is a sequence of instances.

Then elsewhere in the configuration in situations where you need all of these ids together, you can write `local.subnets[*].id`.